# Switching from Chrome OS to Ubuntu 14.02

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome-os

I'm trying to switch from the Chrome OS to Ubuntu 14.02 by doing what I normally do:

```
sudo startunity
```

But it's giving me this issue. Has anyone come across this? Any help is appreciated.

```
 Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method  
"ReleaseDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface 
"org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not 
 permitted)
  Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method 
 "ReleaseDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface 
 "org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

 xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not 
 permitted)
 Unable to set master
 (EE) 
 Fatal server error:
(EE) AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0
(EE) 
(EE) 
 Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
 at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for 
 additional information.
(EE) 
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method 
"TakeDisplayOwnership" with signature "" on interface 
"org.chromium.LibCrosServiceInterface" doesn't exist

(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
 /usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
```

Comment: what command did you use when you installed it? i mean the parameters for crouton. did you incude x11 or xiwi?